# One predictor is a linear combination of another

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

If I try and fit the linear regression

```
lm(y~V1+V3,data=x)
```

with data:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,    
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,    
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L    
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(14.95,
    14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95, 14.95,
    12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59, 12.59,
    12.59, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55,
    10.55, 10.55, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5,
    15.5, 15.5), V3 = c(3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33,
    3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99,
    3.99, 3.99, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02,
    4.02, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96
    ), y = c(3.87904870689558, 4.53964502103344, 8.11741662829825,
    5.14101678284915, 5.25857547032189, 8.43012997376656, 5.9218324119784,
    2.46987753078693, 3.62629429621295, 4.10867605980008, 4.44816359487892,
    2.71962765411473, 2.8015429011881, 2.22136543189024, 0.88831773049185,
    5.57382627360616, 2.99570095645848, -1.93323431325928, 3.40271180312737,
    1.05441718454413, -3.54258964789476, 3.25620068273364, -3.20803558645792,
    -0.831129834329122, -0.000314142794054927, -8.49354648593931,
    11.7022963559562, 6.22698494269212, -4.10509549609558, 15.0305193685594,
    -1.98486866562679, 3.77692131760739, 3.26675717101425, 13.2397209466905,
    6.33304746822537, 9.02654811195804, 6.77162595721038, 6.65703634166947,
    17.9488182721157, 5.19383211472586)), .Names = c("V1", "V2",
    "V3", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame"
```

the coefficient on V3 is NA. I assume this is because somehow V3 is a linear combination of V1.

V1 is a factor that seems to default to dummy coding with the level 'A' set as the reference level. So, how is there a perfect linear combination in V3 and dummy codes for 'B', 'C', and 'D' (as I assume 'A' is the reference level)"?

Comment: Thanks for including the data, it makes it much easier to respond in specific terms.

Comment: The simplest way to see that V3 is a linear combination of V1 is to look at the data - everyone in Level "A" scored 3.33 on V3, everyone in Level "B" scored 3.99, and so on. If any scores on V3 deviated from the others in a particular level of V1, even just a bit, V3 would no longer be a linear combination of V1.  However, since everyone in each group obtained the same score, you could use V1 or V3 as your grouping factor and it wouldn't make any difference.  They are perfectly collinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your covariates matrix looks like:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \delta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

First column is for the intercept, the last is for `V3` and the other three for are for `V1` (already excluded the first column) .

By substracting the first column by the last divided by $\alpha$, we have:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1-\alpha/\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
1-\beta/\alpha & \beta & 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 
1-\gamma/\alpha & 0 & \gamma & 0 & \gamma \\ 
1-\delta/\alpha & 0 & 0 & \delta & \delta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
1-\beta/\alpha & \beta & 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 
1-\gamma/\alpha & 0 & \gamma & 0 & \gamma \\ 
1-\delta/\alpha & 0 & 0 & \delta & \delta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

Now subtracting the first column by a each column of `V1` multiplied by a scalar:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
0 & \beta & 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 
0 & 0 & \gamma & 0 & \gamma \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \delta & \delta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

So, for any $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ you have perfect multicollinearity.

Comment: I forgot about the intercept (1's)! One question on the last step (matrix) :  I would have thought the last column would be exactly the same as one of the others - but it is not given all zeros in the first row except for the last column.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't understood what is the question you mean in your comment, or your comment wasn't a question, but only a remark?

Comment: My question was that I expected perfect multicollinearity to show that one of the columns was a linear combination of the others. But that is not possible is it?

Comment: Yes, it is, given three vectors, A, B and C, they are linear depend (same thing as perfect multicollinearity for the covariate smatrix) if and only if, there exists x,y,z not all equal to 0 such that: $xA + yB + zC = 0$ (0 here means the vector where all it's members are 0). Now, if we multiply $xA$ by the scalar 2, you'll have: 2xA + yB + zC = 0: but wait, if there exists x,y,z not all equal to 0 such that: xA + yB + zC = 0, then there exist x,y,z not all equal to 0 such that: 2xA + yB + zC = 0.

Comment: So, those operations with columns were only a way to make easier for us to see that those vectors are linear dependent. But we can always think in a single step starting by the first matrix of my answer: there exist scalars, not all equal to 0, that multiply each vector (column of the matrix of covariates) that will make their sum equal to zero, it'll just be more difficult to find them directly. In the last matrix, however, it's easy to see that any scalar multiplying the first column and the 0 multiplying the other columns will yield the 0 vector.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that V3 is a linear combination of the levels of V1:

```
summary(lm(V3~V1,data=x))
```

Like so:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 3.330e+00  1.016e-15 3.278e+15   <2e-16 ***
V1B         6.600e-01  1.437e-15 4.593e+14   <2e-16 ***
V1C         6.900e-01  1.437e-15 4.802e+14   <2e-16 ***
V1D         6.300e-01  1.437e-15 4.385e+14   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.213e-15 on 36 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.061e+29 on 3 and 36 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The residual standard error is just accumulated numerical error.

You may also find this form useful in this case: `summary(lm(V3~V1+0,data=x))`